# How to trigger a job, If the currently running job failed?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In my task I need to trigger a same job if its current build failed. 
I don't want the trigger if the build got succeeded.

Is there any plugins or any other method available to do this task?

Comment: Maybe https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

Comment: Do you need to re-run the same job if it is fails or trigger build on the another job ?

Comment: I need to trigger same job

Comment: Do you realize that this is a chance to have an infinitive loop ? If your job fails for each build, it will be trying to run over and over again...

Comment: In that case I can run other job to stop this job

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Downstream Ext Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Downstream-Ext+Plugin) for this:

[image]

`my_project` will be triggered only if this build fails.

**Note**: if you want to trigger the same job, you should realize that this is a chance to have an infinitive loop. If the build always fails, it will be triggered over and over again...

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to use [Naginator Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Naginator+Plugin).

If the build fails, it will be rescheduled to run again after the time you specified. You can choose how many times to retry running the job. For each consecutive unsuccessful build, you can choose to extend the waiting period.

Answer (score 0):

## Jenkins Naginator Plugin

[Jenkins Naginator Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Naginator+Plugin) can be used to automatically reschedule a build after a failure.

This becomes very useful in scenarios where the build fail due to unavoidable reasons like a database connectivity is lost, the file system is not accessible etc.

### Configurations

Rescheduling configuration is available as a post-build-action. There are a number of configurations for you to pick correctly based on your expected (unavoidable) build failure reason.

Read further on the configurations [here](http://www.digizol.com/2013/10/jenkins-retrying-failed-build.html) with a screenshot.